# remove data from jquery easyui combobox

Tags: jquery, jquery-easyui

I'm using the [jQuery EasyUI Combobox](http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/combobox.php) to present a list of data. Is there any way I can remove a particular line from my jQuery EasyUI combobox list with a jQuery EasyUI function or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello i didn't find special function for that in EasyUI Combobox, but you can use [JQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

this is the way to delete selected item:

```
$('.combobox-item-selected').remove(); // Remove selected item
$('.combo-text').val(''); // clear a textfield
```

this is   the way to delete any item by unique value using selectors:

```
$('div[value="ND"]').remove(); // Where ND is unique value
```

i tried this code in [this](http://www.jeasyui.com/demo/main/index.php?plugin=ComboBox&theme=bootstrap&dir=ltr&pitem=Basic) demo of EasyUI Combobox

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find special function, but can use 'getData' and 'loadData' do it.

```
var items = $("#id").combobox('getData');
var newItems = [];
//push the select option if value is not equals '1'
$.each(items, function (index, item) {
    if (item.value != '1') {
        newItems.push(item);
    }
});
$("#id").combobox('loadData', newItems);
```

generally, u may change the selected option. I use below code select the first one.

```
var opts = $("#id").combobox('options');
$("#id").combobox('setValue', newItems[0][opts.valueField]);
```